# OpenCV(4.2.0) Error: Assertion failed ((npoints = prevPtsMat.checkVector(2, CV_32F, true)) >= 0)

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++

I'm learning to use OpenCV and I got this problem: OpenCV(4.2.0) Error: Assertion failed ((npoints = prevPtsMat.checkVector(2, CV_32F, true)) >= 0) in cv::`anonymous-namespace'::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlowImpl::calc, file C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc14\opencv\modules\video\src\lkpyramid.cpp, line 1257.

Help me please, I really don't know how to solve this problem. This is my code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main() {
    cv::VideoCapture cap("video.mp4");

    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        std::cerr << "The video file or video stream could not be opened." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cv::Mat prevFrame, currFrame;
    cv::TermCriteria termcrit(cv::TermCriteria::COUNT | cv::TermCriteria::EPS, 20, 0.03);
    cv::Size winSize(31, 31);

    std::vector<cv::Point2f> prevPoints, currPoints;

    while (true) {
        cap >> currFrame;

        if (currFrame.empty()) {
            break;
        }

        if (prevFrame.empty()) {
            currFrame.copyTo(prevFrame);
            cv::cvtColor(prevFrame, prevFrame, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
            cv::goodFeaturesToTrack(prevFrame, prevPoints, 100, 0.01, 10);
        }

        cv::cvtColor(currFrame, currFrame, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        std::vector<uchar> status;
        std::vector<float> err;

        cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prevFrame, currFrame, prevPoints, currPoints, status, err, winSize, 3, termcrit, 0, 0.001);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < currPoints.size(); i++) {
            if (status[i]) {
                cv::circle(currFrame, currPoints[i], 3, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), -1);
                cv::line(currFrame, prevPoints[i], currPoints[i], cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0));
            }
        }

        cv::imshow("Optical flow", currFrame);

        if (cv::waitKey(30) == 'q') {
            break;
        }

        std::swap(currPoints, prevPoints);
        currFrame.copyTo(prevFrame);
    }

    cv::destroyAllWindows();

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to make Lucas–Kanade method on c++ and I wanted to use it to detect an object in a video image (highlight it).